# Google Script - setValues issue

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm writing a script for a gDoc Spreadsheet and have a little issue with the setValues method.

The code is pretty basic but still desn't work properly.

First there is an Array that is build:

```
var newRow = [date, sRowValues[0][1], sRowValues[0][2], sRowValues[0][4]];
```

No problem so far (I believe) and then I try to write the result to a sheet:

```
destinationSheet.getRange(2,1,1,4).setValues(newRow);
```

And this brings the following error message: Cannot convert (class)@7fb23794 to Object

The following does work though:

```
destinationSheet.getRange(2,2,1,1).setValue("newRow")
```

Any help would be welcome.
Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Range.setValues()` is expecting an array of arrays (two-dimensional array), you're feeding it an array of objects. On the other hand, `Range.setValue()` expects an object (string, number or date), for a single cell.

Try this, which will produce an array with 1 row of 4 columns (matching the dimensions of your range):

```
var newRow = [date, sRowValues[0][1], sRowValues[0][2], sRowValues[0][4] ];
var newData = [newRow];

destinationSheet.getRange(2,1,1,4).setValues(newData);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I will surely try this. Meanwhile I had a workaround for this issue, setting one value at a time with `setValue()`, but this is not the best way to do it for sure.

Comment: Confirm this worked out for me - thanks. Now I have other issues, but that's life, solve one get three..

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea is to define a column array and insert it into a row array.  So, for example, if you wish to create a row with 4 header titles (at the top of the sheet - the sheet's first row), you would do something like this:

```
var columnNamesArray = ['id','name','description','price'];
var headerRowArray = [columnNamesArray];
mySheet.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues(headerRowArray);
```

Alternatively, you can shorten it to:

```
mySheet.getRange(1,1,1,4).setValues([['id','name','description','price']]);
```