# How can i convert a 3D array to 2D array in GAS?

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have one spreadsheet with several sheets and i want to get one range of data, filter it and setvalues of the filtered data to another sheet.
I can do it with .getvalues and loop thru all the values in that array, push the ones i need to a new array and .setvalue (row by row) to the new sheet.
What i really want is to speed up things a lot using a batch .setvalues.
The problem is when i push values to my second array, i end up with a 3D array and .setvalues only accepts 2D arrays.
I've been searching a lot and found similar problems ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30820062/google-apps-script-batch-setvalues-on-sheet), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17469148/google-script-setvalues-issue)), but haven't got the solution for my problem.
I need a faster solution than looping thru row by row to set values.

My code looks like this:

```
var shSales=ss.getSheetByName('Relação de Vendas'), lrowSales=shSales.getLastRow();
var shArchive=ss.getSheetByName('Hx Faturação')
var shSalesData=shSales.getRange(7,1,lrowSales-6,15).getValues();
var InvoicedSales=[];
var deleted=0;

for (var i in shSalesData) {
  if (shSalesData[i][12]!=[] && shSalesData[i][13]!=[] && shSalesData[i][14]!=[]) {
    InvoicedSales[i]=[];
    InvoicedSales[i].push(shSalesData[i]);
    shSales.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+7)-deleted);
    deleted++;
  }
}
var lrowArchive=shArchive.getLastRow();
var range=shArchive.getRange(lrowArchive+1, 1, 2, 15);
range.setValues(InvoicedSales);

SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

Can you help my figure this out?

Comment: Please add sample input data and a [mcve].

Comment: `InvoicedSales.push(shSalesData[i]);`?

Comment: @RobinGertenbach your comment came up while I was writing my answer. In the shortest term possible, you are correct. As for the OP, my answer also explains where and why you are having this issue. I will vote up that comment though!

Comment: @RobinGertenbach Thank you for your answer, beeing the solution also presented by Vytautas, but as i'm new to javascript, i didn't understand it before reading Vytautas comment.

Comment: I'm also new to SO as an active user. Can anyone explain me why the downvotes to the question, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I see you are creating an array from scratch, so you need to find where it turns into a 3D array instead and prevent it by having a proper algorithm that builds your array you wish to push to the spreadsheet.

With a quick debug you can find that the problem really happens in the following 2 lines:

```
InvoicedSales[i]=[];
InvoicedSales[i].push(shSalesData[i]);
```

So after the first line we get a `InvoicedSales[[]]` and after the second line you will have `InvoicedSales[[[data]]]` which is now a 3D array.

A simple resolution to this issue is, as I mentioned, construct the array in a different way. Those 2 lines can be replaced with simply

```
InvoicedSales.push(shSalesData[i]);
```

The drawback of this is that if you wish to retain empty spaces, this will simply create an array that does not reflect data that does not fit your `if` statement. In order to also have blank rows in your array, you have to then include an `else` segment that would `push` an empty array into your `InvoicedSales` so we would have something along the lines of:

```
for (var i in shSalesData) {
  if (shSalesData[i][12]!=[] && shSalesData[i][13]!=[] && shSalesData[i][14]!=[]) {
    InvoicedSales.push(shSalesData[i]);
    shSales.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+7)-deleted);
    deleted++;
  }
  else {
    InvoicedSales.push([])
  }
}
```

So that code would push the array of data to `InvoicedSales` when `if` is fulfilled and push an empty array when `if` is not met. That way if row 1 meets the criteria it is pushed as row 1 and if row 3 meets the criteria next, on the output array it will still be the 3rd row.

Do be careful that by doing this and then using `setValues()` all the empty lines will clear whatever is in that particular row! So a `[[a,b,c],[],[1,2,3]]` will set spreadsheet values to be

```
a b c

1 2 3
```

with the row in the middle being blank regardless of what occupied the cells previously

Comment: Thank you for your effort and excellent explanation, but when i remove the first line:
`InvoicedSales[i]=[];`
i get a _TypeError cannot call method 'push' of undefined_
I must be doing something else wrong, maybe :-(

Comment: @JoséLuísSincereSepúlveda just removing the line is not enough, look closely at your code, originally you have `InvoicedSales[i].push(shSalesData[i]);` so you have to get rid of the `[i]` from `InvoicedSales[i]` as it expects an array inside of the array, but we just want to work with the main array instead

Comment: My bad, i missed that. It worked just fine. Thank you so much and sorry for making you waste extratime with this.